# How do you use Arduino as ESC

Tags: dc-motor

I am trying to find a way to use an Arduino as an ESC for an electric scooter project. I have dual 12v 90w brushed DC motors (from razor e90). I'd also like to be able to get speed data (or voltage/amperage data) from the motors. Also I'm in middle school. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You must use some reading skills 1st https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Arduino%20as%20ESC

Comment: Yes, but most of those are brushless, higher voltages, and for single motors. Also as far as I can tell, none of those have any sort of amperage/voltage sensing.

Comment: You can't use an Arduino as an ESC.  You could use an Arduino as the controller _in_ an ESC, but building an ESC is _not trivial_.  I suggest you do a search on "open source ESC" -- that should get you a lot of hits, you can study from there.  I also suggest that you **do not try** to design an ESC as your first venture into electronics.

Comment: You need to connect it to an H-bridge for bidirectional rotation, or just a single transistor for unidirectional rotation. These are solutions for brushed motors only, not brushless.

Comment: You might be able to find some kind of H-bridge board that you can easily interface with your arduino. It is a hard project but if you want to try, I say go for it. The big problem with higher power electronics projects is that when you do something wrong, you tend to blow up expensive pieces of hardware and that can get expensive and frustrating.

Comment: Regarding Arduino, if someone hasn’t already done what you want you either are wanting the wrong thing or less likely doing something bleeding edge. Sounds sort of defeatist but tends to ring true.